# Appending occurrences and aggregation to the duplicates records

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting, data-structures, collections

This is my file which contains these lines:

```
**name,bus_id,bus_timing,bus_ticket**
yuhindmklwm00409219,958193628,0305delete,2700)
(yuhindmklwm00409219,958193628,0305delete,800)
(yuhindmklwm00409219,959262446,0219delete,62)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,752013801,0220delete,2700)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85382,0126delete,500)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,863056514,0326delete,-2700)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,863056514,0326delete,2700)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85258,0313delete,1000)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85012,0311delete,1000)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85718,0311delete,2700)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,744622574,0322delete,90)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,83704,0215delete,17)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85253,0331delete,-2700)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85253,0331delete,2700)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,752013801,0305delete,2700)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,33165,0315delete,1000)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85018,0319delete,100)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85018,0219delete,100)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85018,0118delete,100)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,90265,0312delete,6)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,02465,0312delete,25)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,857164939,0313delete,15)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,22102,0313delete,4)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,55423,0313delete,100)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,02465,0314delete,1)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,90265,0312delete,1)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,93108,0315delete,25)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,220432304,0315delete,35)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,701211570,0315delete,35)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,28801,0315delete,10)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,93108,0211delete,3)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,93108,02)
```

My final output should contain duplicate records and their occurences with sum amount and percentile.

```
name,bus_id,bus_timing, 60th percentile value of bus_ticket, sum_bus_ticket, occurence)

yuhindmklwm00409219,958193628,0305delete,2000, 2700, 1)
yuhindmklwm00409219,958193628,0305delete,2000, 3500, 2)
.......
.......
......
```

This can be solved by list's but it's not efficient can somebody think of other data structures?

It's ok if you ignore aggregation's like sum or percentile. But at least one aggregation should be there.

This is my percentile function:

```
scala> def percentileValue(p: Int,data: List[Int]): Int = {val firstSort=data.sorted; val k=math.ceil((data.size-1) * (p / 100.0)).toInt; return firstSort(k).toInt}
percentileValue: (p: Int, data: List[Int])Int

scala> val lst=List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
lst: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
scala> percentileValue(60,lst)
res142: Int = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortened the data for better testing. Something like that?

```
val lili = List (List ("yuhindmklwm004092193", "9581936283", "0305delete3", 2700),
List ("yuhindmklwm004092193", "9581936283", "0305delete3", 800),
List ("yuhindmklwm004092193", "9592624463", "0219delete3", 62),
List ("yuhindmklwm004372933", "7520138013", "0220delete3", 2700),
List ("yuhindmklwm004372933", "853823", "0126delete3", 500),
List ("yuhindmklwm004372933", "8630565143", "0326delete3", -2700),
List ("yuhindmklwm004372933", "8630565143", "0326delete3", 2700),
List ("yuhindmklwm004372933", "852583", "0313delete3", 1000))
```

Grouping:

```
scala> lili.groupBy {case (list) => list(0) }.map {case (k, v) => (k, v.map (_(3)))}
res18: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,List[Any]] = Map(yuhindmklwm004372933 -> List(2700, 500, -2700, 2700, 1000), yuhindmklwm004092193 -> List(2700, 800, 62))
```

Mapping on percentileValue:

```
lili.groupBy {case (list) => list(0) }.map {case (k, v) => (k, v.map (_(3)))}.map {case (k, v:List[Int])=> (k, percentileValue (60, v))}
<console>:10: warning: non-variable type argument Int in type pattern List[Int] (the underlying of List[Int]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
              lili.groupBy {case (list) => list(0) }.map {case (k, v) => (k, v.map (_(3)))}.map {case (k, v:List[Int])=> (k, percentileValue (60, v))}
                                                                                                            ^
res22: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Int] = Map(yuhindmklwm004372933 -> 2700, yuhindmklwm004092193 -> 2700)

scala> lili.groupBy {case (list) => list(0) }.map {case (k, v) => (k, v.map (_(3)))}.map {case (k, v:List[Int])=> (k, percentileValue (10, v))}
<console>:10: warning: non-variable type argument Int in type pattern List[Int] (the underlying of List[Int]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
              lili.groupBy {case (list) => list(0) }.map {case (k, v) => (k, v.map (_(3)))}.map {case (k, v:List[Int])=> (k, percentileValue (10, v))}
                                                                                                            ^
res23: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Int] = Map(yuhindmklwm004372933 -> 500, yuhindmklwm004092193 -> 800)
```